# Two Dimensional Matrices in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix

I'm trying to do some operations in two dimensional matrices. I overloaded (+ , - and *) to do the calculations. I have a problem regarding (I believe) memory management. Look at the following code:

```
Mtx M1(rows1,cols1,1.0); //call the constructor 
Mtx M2(rows2,cols2,2.0); //call the constructor 
Mtx M3(rows3,cols3,0.0); //call the constructor 

M3 = M1 + M2;
cout << M3 << endl;

Mtx Mtx::operator+(const Mtx &rhs)
{

double **ETS;
ETS = new double*[nrows];
for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    ETS[i] = new double[rhs.ncols];
}
if (ETS == NULL) {
    cout << "Error Allocation on the Heap" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rhs.ncols; j++) {
        ETS[i][j] = 0.0;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rhs.ncols; j++) {
        ETS[i][j] = ets[i][j];
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rhs.ncols; j++) {
        ETS[i][j] = ETS[i][j] + rhs.ets[i][j];
    }
}

Mtx S(nrows, ncols, ETS);
delete [] ETS;
return S;
}
```

I think my problem is here:

```
Mtx S(nrows, ncols, ETS); 
delete [] ETS;
return S;
```

Is this a proper way to return `ETS`? Or do you think the problem is with the constructor? I got no output when I did the above return!

This is the constructor for `Mtx S(nrows, ncols, ETS);`

```
Mtx::Mtx(int rows, int cols, double **ETS)
{
ets = new double*[nrows];
for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    ets[i] = new double[ncols];
}
for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
        ets[i][j] = ETS[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

My copy constructor:

```
Mtx::Mtx(const Mtx& rhs)
:nrows(rhs.nrows), ncols(rhs.ncols)
    {
ets = new double*[nrows];
for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    ets[i] = new double[ncols];
}

for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rhs.ncols; j++) {
        ets[i][j] = rhs.ets[i][j];
    }
  }
}
```

I overloaded `<<` to print `M3`. It works fine because I tested printing `M1` and `M2`.

I also did the following, and still not working:

```
Mtx S(nrows, ncols, ETS);
for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    delete [] ETS[i];
}
delete [] ETS;
return S;
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with [`boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm) that meant you had to write your own?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: In the link, you can replace version with "release" to always point to latest release, i.e. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

Comment: @Johnsyweb I didn't know about [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm). I have to write my own.

Comment: @JackintheBox: Why do you have to write your own? Also, what does your copy constructor look like? You shouldn't need to use `new`/`delete` here at all.

Comment: The problem may be in `class Mtx`'s copy constructor because `return S` requires a copy construction. If you didn't do deep copy, the result would be wrong.

Comment: @Johnsyweb because I wanted to learn how to create my own. I'm practicing :)

Comment: [Programmers often confuse multidimensional arrays with arrays of pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c). You seem to have done this.

Comment: @Johnsyweb I added the copy constructor to my post.

Comment: @timrau I added the copy constructor to my post.

Comment: Your copy constructor leaks the memory that was previously allocated to the object. Since your class manually manages a resource (memory) you should study [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). In addition, you should learn good practices for [Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: @Blastfurnace I tested the following: `M3 = M1` and it worked fine. So, do you think the problem is in the copy constructor?

Comment: `M3 = M1` uses the assignment operator. You haven't posted `Mtx::operator=` but I'm guessing it also leaks memory. Have you spent some time reading the link in my previous comment about [The Rule Of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I also outputted the result of `M3 = M1 + M2` inside `operator+` and it worked!

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yeah, I think you are right about the assignment operator. I read about The Rule Of Three before, and this not my first time working with this. Why are you guessing that the copy constructor leaks memory? What did you notice?

Comment: On second look, your copy constructor looks okay. Sorry about the confusion. What is the specific problem again? The `operator+` returns a blank matrix?

Comment: @Blastfurnace No worries. `operator+` returns nothing.

Comment: @JackintheBox: Your `operator+()` returns an `Mtx` instance, not "nothing".

Comment: @Johnsyweb I agree it returns `Mtx`, but I don't see it! `cout << M3 << endl;` doesn't print the output which means there is a problem in the return.

Comment: Your code says `Mtx M1(rows1,cols1,1.0); //call the constructor` but you've not provided us with a ctor that takes a `double` as the third and final argument. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

You could instead use

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> >
```

instead of

```
double **
```

that will be more safe as far as bounds are concerned. And you only have to use functions

```
std::vector::size()
```

and

```
std::vector::clear()
```

in the destructor. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a problem where you pointed out.  You have to delete all the memory that is pointed to in the pointers in ETS.  So, it should be more like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nrows; i++) {
    delete [] ETS[i];
}
delete [] ETS;
```

I good rule is that for each call to new you have to call delete;  You allocate the array with `nrows+1` calls to new so you have to delete with the same number.  That's not hard and fast but it'll clue you in when something is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The common way to implement binary arithmetic operators is to define `operator+=` as a class member function and `operator+` as a free-standing function. Note the `+` operator is implemented in terms of the `+=` operator and it takes its left operand ***by copy***. As long as your copy constructor and assignment operator are correct this should work.

```
// member function
Mtx& Mtx::operator+=(const Mtx &rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; ++i) {
            ets[i][j] += rhs.ets[i][j];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

// non-member function
Mtx operator+(Mtx lhs, const Mtx &rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```